# JQuery click for elements added using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a div with class `c` and I am adding some code to this class using Ajax so it ends up looking something like:

```
<div class="c">
  <div class="del" id="1"></div>
  <div class="del" id="2"></div>
  <div class="del" id="3"></div>
</div>
```

My class `c` is static and the divs with class `delete` are added using Ajax. Now what I want is to get the id of the div with class `delete` that I click on.

I was first doing:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    }
);
```

But this doesn't work. I later found out on SO that we should use `.on()` for content added using Ajax. From what I understood, I implemented it the following way:

```
$(".c").on('click','.delete',function(){
    var id = $(".delete").attr('id');
    }
);
```

But this gives me the `id` of the first delete. Could someone please provide a way so that i can get the `id` of the delete I clicked on assuming that the inner divs, namely:

```
<div class="del" id=i></div>
```

are added using Ajax. Thank you.

Comment: use `var id = this.id`

Comment: Wouldn't this give me the id of the class `c`?

Comment: So it works. Could you please explain why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to reselect `.delete` collection again with `$('.delete')`. [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method invoked as getter on a collection of elements, returns an attribute value of the first element in collection. In your case you already have a reference to currently clicked element as `this`. Try this:

```
$(".c").on('click','.delete', function() {
    var id = this.id;
});
```

Also you can access `id` as HTMLElement property, so you don't need to read its attribute.